# Magento 2: Products not showing

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento-2.0

Recently I've uploaded a few products in my Magento 2, they are enabled and inserted in the correct category but they do not appear even if I try to search them, I can see them only if I write the URL directly. what could be the reason?
I tried to refresh Magento cache but nothing's changed.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Magento, **after every products upload, you need do a reindex .**

At Magento 2, to run the reindex, you should setup cron job.

If you want **reindex immediate** then you should run  `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command from Terminal.

Comment: It's working thank you! but is there a way to do an immediate reindex  without running the reindex command?

Comment: not possible without cronJOb or  command

Comment: You can set it to reindex on update at Index Management right?

Comment: You saved me .. I lost few hours tying to figure out why I cannot see uploaded products ... thanks

Comment: I ran but still not working